# Regex & C#: Replace all Special Characters except Emojis

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace all special characters in a string **except the following (which includes alphabetic characters)**:

- :)
- :P
- ;)
- :D
- :(

This is what I have now:

```
string input = "Hi there!!! :)";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

This replaces all special characters. How can I modify this to not replace mentioned characters (emojis) but replace any other special character?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Edited my title. Yes I need to replace every special characters except for the Emojis I've mentioned

Comment: What are "special characters"? For me, `'s'` is a special character because my name starts with it. Perhaps "special" has a different definition for you.

Comment: Calm down :) Edited the title to avoid any further confusion :D @spender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a known technique: match and capture what you need and match only what you want to remove, and replace with the backreference to Group 1:

```
(:(?:[D()P])|;\))|[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]
```

Replace with `$1`. Note I added `\s` to the character class, but in case you do not need spaces, remove it.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3A(%3F%3A%5BD()P%5D)%7C%3B%5C))%7C%5B%5E0-9a-zA-Z%5Cs%5D&i=%3A)%20%20%3AP%20%20%3B)%20%20%3AD%20%20%3A(%20Some%20special%20%7E%40!%24%23%24%5E%26()%0D%0AHi%20there!!!%20%3A)&r=%241)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(:(?:[D()P])|;\))` - Group 1 (what we need to keep):

  - `:(?:[D()P])` - a `:` followed with either `D`, `(`, `)` or `P`
  - `|` - or
  - `;\)` - a `;)` substring
  - (here, you may extend the capture group with more `|`-separated branches).
- `|` - or ...
- `[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]` - match any char other than ASCII digits, letters (and whitespace, but as I mentioned, you may remove `\s` if you do not need to keep spaces).

Comment: Although `(:(?:[D()P])|;\))` is the most compact/efficient way of writing this, I'd be more inclined to list the options more explicitly - i.e. `(:D|:P|:\)|:\(|;\))`. If the list grows much longer, you could then define all emojis in an array, and use to dynamically generate the regex.

Comment: Well, I kept the alternation group inside Group 1, it can still be expanded with other `|`-separated branches.

Comment: I agree that your answer is valid; just proposing an alternate approach `;)`. Regular expressions can unfortunately get quite ugly/confusing when there's lots of brackets involved.

Comment: Yes, that is why the [`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) flag was introduced :). If there are more and more branches, comments and whitespace can help make any pattern readable.

Comment: For example though, what if we wanted to expand your regex to include `:-)`, `:^)`, `;=)` and `=^.^=`? Of course it's possible, but the end result could become rather difficult to read.

Comment: @TomLord: This is already close to opinion-based answer :) I find all emojis difficult to read. Although I do not consider myself a Web-Asperger :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a RegEx to match all emojis and select them out of the text

```
string input = "Hi there!!! :)";
string output = string.Concat(Regex.Matches(input, "[;|:][D|P|)|(]+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value));
```

Pattern `[;|:][D|P|)|(]+`

`[;|:]` starts with : or ;

`[D|P|)|(]` ends with D, P, ) or (

`+` one or more